# Scripts for resizing image to a specific width and height

Tags: php

Hello I have a form which is uploading Six images to a generated folder by a function in PHP

In here beside uploading I want to make my images 640*480 width and height.

Can you please write for me scripts for resizing images to above mentioned size.

Here is my code:

```
    foreach ($_FILES as $file) 
    {

mkdir("PropertyImages/$ImageID");   
for($x = 0; $x < count($files['name']); $x++)
{
  $name=$files['name'][$x];
  $tmp_name=$files['tmp_name'][$x];
     if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "PropertyImages/$ImageID/".$name))
     {

         $imagequery="INSERT INTO propertyimages(ImageID, ImageName, ImagePath) VALUES('$ImageID', '$name', 'PropertyImages/$ImageID/$name')";
         $imagequeryrun=$connection->query($imagequery);
         if( $connection->error ) exit( $connection->error );
         echo 'Image <b>'. $name .'</b> Uploaded Successfully <br>';
          echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="5; URL=Property_Insert_Page.php">';

     }

}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this script:

http://shiftingpixel.com/2008/03/03/smart-image-resizer/

Download link:
http://shiftingpixel.com/downloads/image-1.4.1.zip